# Read binary file with ARM assembly

Tags: android, assembly, arm

I would you like write a simple program that open a binary file and read every byte. I try to do this using an Android device with this syscalls (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/cd58770/libc/SYSCALLS.TXT) with follow code

```
...
ldr r0, =binaryfile
mov r1, #2
mov r7, #5
svc #0

loop:
ldr r0,=Handle
ldr r0,[r0]
ldr R1,=Array
mov R2,#80
mov r7,#3 @read syscall
svc #0
...
Handle: .skip 4
Array: .skip 80
binaryfile: .asciz "file.bin"
.end
```

But after the open syscall, the value of Handle is always 0xfffffffe

Any suggestion?

Comment: Run your program under `strace`, to log all the system calls it makes.  It's an easy way to catch errors where you pass the wrong arg.  BTW, failed system calls always return `-ERRNO`, so you could look up what errno=-2 means.  Maybe EFAULT, ENOENT, or something.  (Or just use strace)

Comment: Wait a minute, where do you store the `open(2)` return value into `Handle`?  It looks like you enter the loop with it in `r0`.  And why not keep it in a register the whole time?  You can also hoist the `ldr r0,=Handle` out of the loop.  (Check the ABI to make sure `svc #0` perserves all registers except the return value, but most platforms do work that way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not completely correct, you must add `ldr r0,=Handle` out of the loop (as suggest by Peter) and you have also to review the parameters of the open syscall(http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html). This is a working example:

```
...
@ Open an input file for reading
ldr r0,=binaryfile      @ set Name for input file
mov r1,#0
ldr r2,=0666            @ permissions
mov r7,#5
swi 0 

@ Save the file handle in memory:
ldr r1,=Handle     @  load input file handle
str r0,[r1]              @  save the file handle


loop:
ldr r0,=Handle           @ load input file handle
ldr r0,[r0]
ldr r1,=readBuffer
mov r2,#16 
mov r7, #3
swi 0                    @ read the integer into R0
...
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you added a comment explaining why you changed the 2nd arg of `open` from 2 to 0.  Presumably to O_RDONLY.  I also would have renamed `Handle` to fd or something, because in Unix they're called descriptors, not handles.

Comment: I probably would have avoided static storage for it entirely; either pushing the fd and then reloading with a stack-relative address, or keeping the value in a register that the system call doesn't read or destroy.  Or at least access it with a displacement relative to the `readBuffer`, so you only need one `ldr reg, =address` instruction.  Over-use of static storage in asm examples is a pet peeve of mine.  But this comment is more addressed to the OP, you're just keeping your code as close as possible to the OP's clunky static storage.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes the 2nd arg of open (flags arg) is O_RDONLY, and yes descriptor is a better name :)